# MathJax not included in Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, backbone.js

I was using cdn path for MathJax file, but it was not working.
So as suggested on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/aDIAR8ZxneI , I installed MathJax file locally and included in index.html
In web it still works fine, but in cordova app the MathJax file is not included.

Comment: To be clear, in your Cordova app did you copy the JS file into the www folder and include it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cordova, no need to install mathJax. Including mathJax in following way fix the issue/error.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    // add your configuration, see following for example
    showProcessingMessages: false,
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> </script>
```

Including file  as "//cdn.mathjax.org/..." or "https://cdn.mathjax.org/..." will not include mathJax file.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.